# how to hide the particular row in the Gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, row, show-hide

How can I hide a particular row in a GridView?

For Example

If I click 2/4/1/7  it will hide 3/5/2/8 correspodingly how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
YourDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
YourDataGridView.Rows[rowIndexToHide].Visible = false;
```

The first line set the CurrentCell to null because you can hide the selected row.